# Accessing EJBs deployed in WildFly from an application running in Jboss5

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, wildfly-8, jboss5.x

I am running an application in integration with another team's application.
My application is running on **JBoss5 and jdk6**
Other Application is running on **Wildfly8 with jdk8**

My application calls an **EJB Bean** deployed as part of other application but this look up fails.

I am not willing to migrate to wildfly as it could be little time taking task but I am not even getting rid of it.

Any suggestions guys so I can avoid this migration.

Answer (score 0):

See the below links which describes to configure an EJB client in JBoss:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance